# cypress script failed with ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined

Tags: handlebars.js

I am new to React and cypress. We are using Cypress script to cover React developed code. I am able to launch application in browser However when we use cy.visit('application url') then script fails with below error message :
ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined
After getting this error I added handlebars dependency in package.json file and restarted server. This also didn't the problem. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try to do something , if it is true , share  it here

Comment: I have added dependency for handlebars in package.json file . Also I could see this handlebars call in index.html file   which I commented to see any difference However that didn't make any difference on application and on this error I am getting for handlebars.

Comment: what I doubt is When we invoke application URL then it's redirected to another URL on browser where we enter login credentials and then it takes to application home page, could this be reason ?